# Extracting arc parameters from a DXF using EZDXF Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocad, dxf

I am trying to extract the Arc Parameters from a `DXF` using `Ezdxf`.

So far I have been able to extract the `center`, `start_angle`, `end_angle` and `radius`.

Is there a way, I can find out the direction of the arc, i.e., clockwise or anti-clockwise?

I am using the code :

```
dwg_file = ezdxf.readfile("drawing.DXF")
modelspace = dwg_file.modelspace()
for entity in modelspace:
        dxf_type = entity.dxftype()
        print " Entity attributes ", entity.dxfattribs()
```

For an Arc, all I receive is :

```
{u'layer': u'0', u'handle': u'8A', u'center': (1713.461909760174, 1108.553092696682, 0.0), u'start_angle': 359.9999999999935, u'end_angle': 70.0000000000344, u'radius': 4.999999999995392, u'owner': u'2'}
```

Comment: Do you have any code to provide? This would help anyone that would like to help.

Comment: I find it odd that `EZDXF` converts the radian values held by DXF groups 50 & 51 to degrees.

Comment: @LeeMac angles are always stored as degrees in the DXF file, but returned as radians by AutoLISP, see also the DXF reference for group code 50-58, ezdxf returns always the values stored in the DXF file.

Comment: @mozman Thank you, I wasn't aware of that difference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARC goes always counter clockwise around the extrusion vector, which is (0, 0, 1) by default and the usual case for 2D arcs.